# subdirectory with 3rd party library gets not compiled

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to use rpclib from [here](https://github.com/rpclib/rpclib). I started a new project with `main.cpp` and `CMakeLists.txt` and copied the `rpclib` as a subdirectory into my project:

My code is exactly the example from rpclib and looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rpc/server.h"

void foo() {
    std::cout << "foo was called!" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Creating a server that listens on port 8080
    rpc::server srv(8080);

    // Binding the name "foo" to free function foo.
    // note: the signature is automatically captured
    srv.bind("foo", &foo);

    // Binding a lambda function to the name "add".
    srv.bind("add", [](int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    });

    // Run the server loop.
    srv.run();

    return 0;
}
```

and my CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(RPC_Test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_subdirectory(rpclib)
include_directories(rpclib/include)

add_executable(RPC_Test main.cpp)
```

As I understood, the line `add_subdirectory(rpclib)` takes care of adding the rpclib and builds its content during building the `RPC_Test`-Project. It seems, I am wrong. Nothing within rpclib gets build and the build-process RPC_Test fails with a linker-error:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/seba/CLionProjects/rpc-cpp/cmake-build-debug-system --target RPC_Test -- -j 3
Scanning dependencies of target RPC_Test
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/RPC_Test.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable RPC_Test
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "rpc::detail::dispatcher::enforce_arg_count(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      void rpc::detail::dispatcher::bind<void (*)()>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, void (*)(), rpc::detail::tags::void_result const&, rpc::detail::tags::zero_arg const&)::'lambda'(clmdep_msgpack::v2::object const&)::operator()(clmdep_msgpack::v2::object const&) const in main.cpp.o
      void rpc::detail::dispatcher::bind<main::$_0>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, main::$_0, rpc::detail::tags::nonvoid_result const&, rpc::detail::tags::nonzero_arg const&)::'lambda'(clmdep_msgpack::v2::object const&)::operator()(clmdep_msgpack::v2::object const&) const in main.cpp.o
  "rpc::detail::dispatcher::enforce_unique_name(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      void rpc::detail::dispatcher::bind<void (*)()>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, void (*)()) in main.cpp.o
      void rpc::detail::dispatcher::bind<void (*)()>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, void (*)(), rpc::detail::tags::void_result const&, rpc::detail::tags::zero_arg const&) in main.cpp.o
      void rpc::detail::dispatcher::bind<main::$_0>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, main::$_0) in main.cpp.o
      void rpc::detail::dispatcher::bind<main::$_0>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, main::$_0, rpc::detail::tags::nonvoid_result const&, rpc::detail::tags::nonzero_arg const&) in main.cpp.o
  "rpc::server::run()", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "rpc::server::server(unsigned short)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "rpc::server::~server()", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [RPC_Test] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/RPC_Test.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/RPC_Test.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [RPC_Test] Error 2
```

What is missing?

Comment: You added the include file but do not link against the lib. You need to build the lib first then (depending on your project) copy the libs output somewhere in your project and tell cmake to link against the created libs. So the first step would be to clone the repository and build it on your machine. Are you able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `target_link_libraries(RPC_Test PRIVATE rpc)` after the definition of the `RPC_Test` target . `rpc` here is the name of the library target defined in `rpclib`'s `CMakeLists.txt`, not just the base name of the resulting binary artifact.

When using a target name with `target_link_libraries` like that CMake will not only add `-lrpc` to the linker invocation, but also automatically add the include directories necessary to use the library and ensure that the `rpc` library is built before `RPC_Test`. In particular, this means you can also remove the `include_directories` call when you use `target_link_libraries(RPC_Test PRIVATE rpc)`.